# How to get off Using temporary; Using filesort from my query

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

Explain

```
SELECT * 
FROM `EventTimes` 
LEFT JOIN Events on event_id=Events.id
WHERE festival_id = 12 
ORDER BY time;
```

for Events table I have these fields:

```
id
name
festival_id
```

, etc.

for EventTimes table I have:

```
id
event_id
time
```

, etc.

I create index for EventTimes:`create index eventid_time on EventTimes (event_id, time)`
I also create an index for Events:`create index ev_festivalid on Events (festival_id)`

but I get

for Events:

```
Select_type: Simple
Table : Events
Type : ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,ev_festivalid
key : ev_festivalid
key_len: 5
ref: const
rows : 14
Extra : Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

for EventTimes:

```
Select_type: Simple
Table : EventTimes
Type : ref
possible_keys: eventid_time
key : eventid_time
key_len: 5
ref: dbname.Events.id
rows : 1
Extra : Using where
```

How to avoid to have Using temporary; Using filesort in Events?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the filesort is that the rows come back ordered by festival_id, and you are re-ordering them by time, so mysql needs to re-sort the results. I don't see a simple way around that given your schema and query. If I were you I wouldn't be too worried about the filesort. It's really not as bad as it sounds. Read [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/) for more info.

I should also point out that your use of `LEFT JOIN` doesn't make sense. Since your `WHERE` clause references the optional table, it negates the outer join. You should consider re-writing the query.

Comment: How do you sugest to rewrite, one event has different times and also many events have one festival and has to show the list ordering by time